# Is there an adjective for a curve whose concavity does not change signs over the range of interest?

Tags: terminology, curves

If the slope of a curve does not change signs within the range of interest, we say that it is "monotonic" over that range. Is there an equivalent adjective that indicates the absence of an inflection point in the range of interest?

Comment: I once had a discussion about this with some of my friends, and it was suggested that 'conotonic' be used for this. A search reveals that this term has been independently invented [elsewhere](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/lms/101/talks/0522lakkis.pdf). But it's definitely rare enough to need a definition on first use.

Comment: @OscarCunningham, good to know! And cool that you arrived at the same word as others independently.
Can you expound the rationale for this term? If monotonic is a combination of greek roots meaning "constant tone", conotonic would be..."conical tone'?
I would have expected the corollary to be something like "monokoilic". (https://www.linguee.com/english-greek/translation/concave.html)

Comment: I guess it's just a portmanteau of 'convex/concave' and 'monotonic'. The word 'monokoilic' would definitely make more sense from a grammatical perspective.